# Replicate UISegmentedControl with UIButtons - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, uisegmentedcontrol

I didnt like the style of UISegmentedControl, hence i tried to change the way it looked, but I couldnt attach images to its buttons. I just didnt change at all.

Now i'm looking at how to replicate that function with 4 UIButtons.

I've setup 4 UIButtons in interface builder, added different tag numbers to them.

What i cannot accomplish is when a button is tapped, it should be "selected" and the other buttons should be Unselected.

How can i connect all of them?

And if there was a way to change the UISegmented control looks, i would need all this effort.

thanks for the help guys

this is for iPhone OS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using 4 buttons, it is not too difficult to turn off all the others.  Here is some code to get you started:

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(NSInteger)activeButtonIndex {
    for (int i = 0; i < [buttons count]; i++) {
        MYButton *button = [buttons objectAtIndex:i];
        if (i == activeButtonIndex) {
            [button setDepressed:YES];
        } else {
            [button setDepressed:NO];
        }
    }
}
- (void)button1Pressed:(id)sender { [self buttonPressed:1]; }
- (void)button2Pressed:(id)sender { [self buttonPressed:2]; }
- (void)button3Pressed:(id)sender { [self buttonPressed:3]; }
- (void)button4Pressed:(id)sender { [self buttonPressed:4]; }
```

Important setup to note here:

1. You will need to subclass your uibutton to make it have a `depressed` state.  This way, if an item is selected, you simply swap out the image or background of the button to make it looked depressed.
2. `buttons` is an array that is filled with this subclassed uibutton object.  You would set it up in viewDidLoad;

Comment: as UIButton is a UIControl subclass it already has selected property defined there

Comment: then you can choose a different name for it.